# What is the difference between two DAG scheduler times in Spark run log?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I run a spark job and it logs what is going on with the process.
In the end it gives two types of times which refers to completion times.
What is the difference between those two types.

Is this read and write difference or aggregation overhead added or something else?

```
DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 1 (runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78) finished in 41.988 s
DAGScheduler:54 - Job 0 finished: runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78, took 67.610115 s
```

LONGER OUTPUT

```
.
.
.
2019-01-15 21:25:32 INFO  TaskSetManager:54 - Finished task 2974.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5956) in 898 ms on 172.17.6.100 (executor 8) (2982/2982)
2019-01-15 21:25:32 INFO  TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
2019-01-15 21:25:32 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - ResultStage 1 (runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78) finished in 41.988 s
2019-01-15 21:25:32 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 0 finished: runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78, took 67.610115 s
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  SparkHadoopWriter:54 - Job job_20190115212425_0001 committed.
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@4d4d8fcf{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Stopped Spark web UI at http://node-100.iris-cluster.uni.lux:4040
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Shutting down all executors
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asking each executor to shut down
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2019-01-15 21:25:45 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
```

What is the correct approach to evaluate such output log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider if the DAG scheduler maintains a hash-map to collect the sorted list from its "n" partitions. Then, on receiving the list from the last partition, the result-staging step would get over. However, the list of numbers in this last partitions has to be inserted into the hash-map. This would take: log(total-no-of-elements / no.of partition) times -- let it be log(nip) where nip is the number of elements in a partition. Furthermore, reading the entire list of sorted numbers (to write to a file) would take another log N times. Therefore, in total, we need "2 log N" extra time.

Therefore, if you increase the no of partitions (i.e, no of worker nodes), from 2 to 2^4, the final lag would change from say: 250 units to approximately 31 units.

Hope this would help!